# Define the output of PadeApproximant as a function

Tags: functions, output

I am trying to do

```
pad[t_] := PadeApproximant[t Log[t], {t, 1, {2, 1}}] 
pad[t] // Simplify //Factor
pad[1]
Plot[pad[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

The last two lines do not work. Why? How to fix them?

Comment: Try `=` instead of `:=` or use `Evaluate` in `pad[t_] := Evaluate[PadeApproximant[..]]`.

Comment: If you're wondering why that suggestion of @MichaelE2 works, it's because `:=` does not evaluate its right hand side before substituting. So it substitutes `1` verbatim into `PadeApproximant[t Log[t], {t, 1, {2, 1}}] `, to get `PadeApproximant[1 Log[1], {1, 1, {2, 1}}]`, which doesn't make any sense to Mathematica. By using `=`, you evaluate the rhs first, and then `1` gets substituted into the *output* of `PadeApproximant[t Log[t], {t, 1, {2, 1}}]`.

Comment: @thorimur: I did. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Conversion of comments to a community wiki answer:*

**Michael E2:**

Try `=` instead of `:=` or use `Evaluate` in `pad[t_] := Evaluate[PadeApproximant[..]]`.

**thorimur:**

If you're wondering why that suggestion of @MichaelE2 works, it's because `:=` does not evaluate its right hand side before substituting. So `pad[1]` substitutes `1` verbatim into `PadeApproximant[t Log[t], {t, 1, {2, 1}}]`, to get `PadeApproximant[1 Log[1], {1, 1, {2, 1}}]`, which doesn't make any sense to Mathematica. By using `=`, you evaluate the rhs first, and then `1` gets substituted into the *output* of `PadeApproximant[t Log[t], {t, 1, {2, 1}}]`.